# Android Canvas and xml file

Tags: android, canvas

I have some methods for drawing simple objects using canvas. I need use use it together with xml file storing layout. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new yourCustomView(getApplicationContext());
    }

    private class yourCustomView extends View {

        public yourCustomView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
        }

    }
}
```

and there is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <package.name.here.yourCustomView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Why it does not working properly?

Comment: @Guardanis: not a duplicate, since the linked Q&A is only applicable to **`ViewGroup`** extensions, which isn't the case here.

Comment: @waclaw: Your custom view may have a `0x0` size, meaning it's effectively not visible, hence no drawing is required. Can you try switching out the `wrap_content`s for `match_parent`s (or fixed width/height values > 0)?

Comment: Edit: yeah, you're right.